# XML file containing Ampersands

Tags: xml

**Problem**

XML file with ampersands (&) is ok with few records but gives errors on opening if there's thousands of records

**Scenario**

If I don't convert ampersands (&) to `&amp`; its ok on few records but not if there's approx 28K records.

**What I did**

php's `htmlspecialchars(0)` fixes this as ampersands needs to be converted to `&amp;`

**But...**

Whyis it ok with few records to use unconverted ampersands? (&)

Very curious to know the answer!

I tested this by opening it in Chrome directly and also with MS Excel.

Regards to all

Comment: You need to supply a reproducible example, including details of the XML parser you are using. Unescaped ampersands in XML are always an error, and a parser should always report it (except of course when you're using them as defined in the spec, e.g. for a numeric character reference)/

Comment: No unescaped ampersands are acceptable in XML, except the one used in `&amp` to escape them. Please [edit] your post to include sample XML with unescaped ampersands that will open OK in Chrome to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, apologies for the delay. I will replicate the issue with some bogus data (as the original is confidential) and will post back. Regards!